# Getting an error while using begin and end iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

```
vector <vector<int> > v8;
int N;
cin >> N;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        temp.push_back(x);
    }
    v8.push_back(temp);
    
}

vector <int> ::iterator it;
for (it = v8.begin(); it < v8.end(); it++)
{
    cout << (*it) << " ";
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
no operator "=" matches these operandsC/C++(349)
intro.cpp(161, 13): operand types are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>> = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> *, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>>
```

How should I solve this??

Comment: `vector<int>::iterator it;` iterates over a `vector<int>` but you're using it to traverse a `vector<vector<int>>`.  You can't do that.  Maybe you meant `vector<vector<int>>::iterator it;`  Also, unless you've defined `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const vector<int>&)` somewhere then `cout << *it` will also be a problem.

Comment: Side note... May I suggest _not_ using two different variables with the names `N` and `n`?  It's just begging for trouble.  There is nothing wrong with using more than one character for a variable name...  In fact, it's preferable because it allows you to convey actual meaning.

Comment: And I think you want `it < v8.end()` to be `it != v8.end()`

Comment: `v8.begin()` does not return `vector<int>::iterator`, but `vector<vector<int>>`. Dereferencing `it` produces a `vector<int>`. Also, use `it != v8.end()`, not `it < v8.end()`, because iterators only guarantee non-equal comparison. The `for` initialization should be written as `vector<int>::iterator it = v8.begin()` or `auto it = v8.begin()`, do not initialize `it` outside the loop.

Comment: don't use `>` or `<` on iterators, only `==` and `!=`

Comment: @rioV8 I've just started with STL, so yeah I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @jkb yup fixed it now :)

Comment: @paddy yes, you are right!!... I declared a 2D vector and made a 1D iterator, my bad 

Comment: Instead of explicitly defining the type of iterators, you can use `auto`. Makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that `it` is an **iterator** to 1D `vector<int>` while `b8.begin()` gives us an iterator to a 2D `vector<vector<int>>`. So these iterators are not compatible with each other. That is, you cannot use the iterator `it` to traverse a 2D vector.

You can solve this by changing `vector <int> ::iterator it;` as shown below:

```
    vector <vector<int>> ::iterator it;   //change made here. Now it is an iterator to a 2D vector
    for (it = v8.begin(); it != v8.end(); it++)  
    {
        
        for(auto i = (*it).begin(); i != (*it).end();++i) // i is an iterator to a 1D vector
        {
            cout << (*i) << " ";//it changed to i
        }
        
    }
```

Another option would be to use `auto` with range-based `for` loop as shown below:

```
for (auto &row: v8)
{
    for(auto &col: row)
    {
        cout << col << " ";
    }
      
}
```

Comment: hey, can you tell me why in this code have you used '&' after auto, correct me if I'm wrong but I guess it means that we are passing values by reference... what's the need to pass by reference here if we are just printing stuff here 

Comment: @MridulVerma As you suspected `&` means by reference which means that we are directly working on the actual element instead of working on a copy of the element. For example, if you remove the `&` then it will mean that we are working on the copy of that entity. So whatever changes you make when you don't use `&`, it will not affect the actual entity. On the other hand, if you are using `&` then any change we make on the entity we are changing the actual entity. In your example, we are just printing so you can skip using `&`. Also, using `&` might be faster because there is no copying involved.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through vectors in `v8`, enumerating their elements, use range-based `for` loops.

```cpp
for (auto& v: v8) {
    for (auto& it: v) {
        std::cout << it << ' ';
    }
}
```